# run sofware for a fixed time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a batch file which is calling other batch file. Sometimes the second batch file gives an error (because the license for the software I am running is not found). When the error hits, a window pop ups and I need to close manually (undesirable because it needs to run in a loop).
I would like to call the second batch file and if it didn't finish to run after 90seconds, kill it and go to the next line of my first batch file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

`Pause`, `sleep`, `timeout`, and a few others can help you.

I would suggest timeout.

`timeout /t 90`

Here's some more info: http://www.wikihow.com/Delay-a-Batch-File

To do exactly what you want you'll have to work in some logic to decide what to do after the `timeout`, but you will likely use a loop after that. It depends on the structure of your code. Maybe toggle a boolean variable to determine if you want to go to the top of the script.